# In terms of using and accessing sensors on mobile phones, what is the difference between accessing through a mobile app or web browser

Tags: android, architecture, android-sensors, mobile-website, als

Pretty much what the title says, Based on the image, how would accessing, for example the ALS (ambient light sensor) through a website be different to accessing the same or similar sensor via an application. Would there be any differences?[taken from: https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/sensors/sensor-stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH5PD.png)

Comment: If you need to make use of hardware, you're generally better off writing a mobile app.  Some sensors may have APIs in javascript that you can use, but not all of them will.

Comment: For example ambient light APIs are experimental and not well supported by all browsers.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AmbientLightSensor#browser_compatibility

Comment: Ah okay! Would the 'Stack'(not to sure on what the word is) look the same as shown by the image i shared for browsers and apps. as in would they both be in the "applications". Im only really interested in the differences (if there are any) for example, are the way in which the permissions are requested and granted different? Apologies if i am being confusing this is a new area for me.

Comment: Anything running through a mobile browser would get several extra layers, depending on how you want to model it.  The aplication layer would be replaced by browser.  Then you'd add a JS interpreter above that.  Then you'd add experimental APIs.  Then you'd add  a web app.  You could collapse some of those levels, depending on what you want to show-  while all the things in that list and the original image are real things, there's some flexibility in how you label things.